# How to use font Awesome instead of images in jquery rating stars

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, raty

I am using **jquery.raty.min.js** in order to show star rating ,In js method I have option to change the display start image like

```
starOff:"/images/star_none.png",

starOn:"/images/star_full.png"
```

But here i want to use font Awesome classes like

```
<i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star"></i>
```

I have tried placing class like below

```
starOff:"<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>",

starOn:"<i class='fa fa-star'></i>"
```

but its not working can anyone help in doing this.

Comment: `staffOff` and `starOn` seems to change the `src` attribute of an image or the CSS `background` property. You can not create an icon this way.

Comment: so can you suggest me how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure how your jquery or javascript code works. So I can not help you more with it unless you add more code.

Comment: Could you post the whole code? Maybe there is a way to create `<i>` isntead of `<img>`

Comment: I have not customized any code i have used based on this doc

http://wbotelhos.com/raty/

Comment: you may have to manually alter the dom structure created by raty plugin after initialization. could you post the dom structure after the raty plugin was initialized

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The short answer** to this question is to use the most recent update of [Raty (2.7.0)](http://github.com/wbotelhos/raty/archive/2.7.0.zip) (as of the last edit to this response) and look into the 'starType' attribute. When you're setting up the the element you will do something like this:

```
$('div').raty({
  // This is the config you need to change the tag from image to icon
  starType : 'i'
});
```

**Here's some more detail...** If you look into the [CSS](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty/blob/master/lib/jquery.raty.css) file and the [fonts](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty/tree/master/lib/fonts) files, you will see how they set up the `<i>` tag to work with a specific font. From there its a simple task to identify what each class's `:before` content will be. First make sure to include FontAwesome, and then configure your CSS like so (specific to FontAwesome):

```
.cancel-on-png, .cancel-off-png, .star-on-png, .star-off-png, .star-half-png {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

  /*This is the important part*/
  font-family: "FontAwesome";

  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  speak: none;
  text-transform: none;
}

.cancel-on-png:before {
  /*the "\f057" represents an unfilled circle with an x in it*/
  /*each of these can be configured to be whichever icon you would like*/
  /*fore more information on the icon code, look at the link listed below*/
  content: "\f057";
}

.cancel-off-png:before {
  content: "\f05c";
}

.star-on-png:before {
  content: "\f005";
}

.star-off-png:before {
  content: "\f006";
}

.star-half-png:before {
  content: "\f123";
}
```

The complete list of CSS content values for FontAwesome can be found [here](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/)

---

The end product looks something like this:

```
<div>
  <i title="Cancel this rating!" class="raty-cancel cancel-off-png" data-alt="x"></i>&nbsp;
  <i data-alt="1" class="star-off-png" title="Bad"></i>&nbsp;
  <i data-alt="2" class="star-off-png" title="Below Average"></i>&nbsp;
  <i data-alt="3" class="star-off-png" title="Average"></i>&nbsp;
  <i data-alt="4" class="star-off-png" title="Above Average"></i>&nbsp;
  <i data-alt="5" class="star-off-png" title="Great"></i>
  <input name="score" type="hidden">
</div>
```

When configured like this:

```
$(div).raty({
  readOnly    : readOnly,
  cancel      : !readOnly,
  noRatedMsg  : 'This component has not been rated yet',
  half        : true,
  starType    : 'i',
  hints       : ['Bad', 'Below Average', 'Average', 'Above Average', 'Great'],
  click       : function(score, event) {
    console.log("The score is:", score);
  }
});
```

I know it's been 3 months, but I hope this helps someone!

Comment: @RJD22 Thanks for leaving the comment! Its nice to know I've helped :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a simple way without modifying a little bit the plugin itself. If you look at the `jquery.raty.js` file, search for:

```
$('<img />', { src : icon, alt: i, title: title }).appendTo(this);
```

That's creating image elements,

What you need to Do is to create the icon instead. I think that changing it for somethihng like:

```
$('<i />', { class : icon  }).appendTo(this);
```

But usage would be:

```
starOff:"fa fa-star-o",

starOn:"fa fa-star"
```

I haven't tested it but that should be something to start, and probably you will need to adapt the icon look with CSS

Comment: Any errors? Can you see the `<i>` created in the Dom at least?

Comment: Hi its working as the way i followed ur suggestions now displaying is fine but while giving rating i am unable to give previously on mouseover it used to change image and onclick it used to give me score but now its not working.

Comment: Maybe you should just use the images... If you are worried about quality in retina devices, just upload it a 2x of size

Comment: If you look into the documentation on the most recent release of Raty, they have added functionality to compensate for this feature. You no longer have to change the source code. I have posted the solution below with examples of how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I could not have catch the point of the existing answers, but I found it was not hard to use fontawesome icons in raty 2.7.1.
Here are my codes.

html:

```
<div class="score-star" id="star-appearance" rel="score-appearance">
</div>
```

css:

```
.score-star {
    color: #07b062;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

js:

```
$('.score-star').each(function () {
    $(this).raty({
        number: 5,
        starType: 'i',
        starOff: 'fa fa-star-o',
        starOn: 'fa fa-star'
    });
});
```

raty:

```
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/raty/2.7.1/jquery.raty.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/raty/2.7.1/jquery.raty.min.js"></script>
```

fontawesome:

```
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hope it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please check font size and color.. add property font size and color.

Answer (score 0):

With font awesome 5, code should look like:

```
.star-on-png, .star-off-png, .star-half-png {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

  /*This is the important part*/
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';

  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  speak: none;
  text-transform: none;
}

.star-on-png:before {
  content: "\f005";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.star-off-png:before {
  content: "\f005";
}

.star-half-png:before {
  content: "\f5c0";
  font-weight: 900;
}
```